# Flutter Build failed with an exception for Geolocation plugin

Tags: flutter, dart-pub, flutter-dependencies

Whenever I'm trying to include flutter `geolocation`(https://github.com/loup-v/geolocation) plugin I'm getting following error.

```
Initializing gradle...
Resolving dependencies...
Running 'gradlew assembleDebug'...
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
Finished with error: Gradle build failed: 1
```

My `pubspec.yml` dependancies list is

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  google_sign_in: "^3.0.2"
  firebase_auth: "^0.5.5"
  shared_preferences: "^0.4.1"
  cloud_firestore: "^0.7.2"
  firebase_storage: "^0.2.5"
  image_picker: "^0.4.1"
  progress_hud: "^0.2.2"
  cached_network_image: "^0.4.1"
  intl: "^0.15.6"
  path: "^1.5.1"
  geolocation: "^0.2.1"
```

My `app>build.gradle` code

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.bhramaan.bhramaan"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

What's going wrong?

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14874 might have suggestions

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I've already checked that also. But, till now no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three things I can suggest to help. The first is to do a full rebuild by first running `flutter clean` and then running again. Occasionally things get a little bit messed up between flutter & android, and that helps.

The next thing I would do is check that you're getting the same version of all the Play services. For some reason gradlew sometimes messes that up. Run `gradlew app:dependencies` from the `android` (or `./gradlew` if you're on mac/linux). If you're getting different versions, add them all as dependencies of the same version.

For example, in my `android/app/build.gradle`, I had to set

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:15.0.2'
```

even though Gradle should have sorted that out.  In particular look out for `com.google.android.gms:play-services-location` as it's a dependency of the geolocation package. Same goes for the `com.android.support` libraries.

If that still doesn't work, try running the gradle build directly, and in particular looking at the stack trace (`gradlew app:build --stacktrace` from the `android` folder) to see if it tells you anything. You could then post that, or take a look at the generic Android questions for a solution. It could be that you need to enabler multi-dex, although I don't think so.

Comment: Thanks for this info. But, not super acquainted with all these level of android configuration stuff. I tried ```flutter clean```. But, that didn't work. Tried to run those ```gradlew app:dependencies``` & ```./gradlew``` commands but those also didn't work. Maybe I need to install Gradle on my system. But Gradle website seems down from yesterday. I've posted my app>build.gradle file in my post. Is there anything wrong in that, which may be causing this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is an issue with geolocation gradle version of firebase and your flutter version being incompatible. Try adding `multiDexEnabled true` to your build gradle. If that does not solve it open your flutters android project in android studio and go to the geolocation build gradle and change dependencies version to `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'` & at the bottom update the play services to `api "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.+"`.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I've fixed this by following the steps as mentioned by @rmtmckenzie.

In my `android/app/build.gradle` I added following piece of code &

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
    }
}
```

and enabled `multiDexEnabled true`

```
defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

With this setting now, my whole app working fine.

Answer (score 0):

In your app's top level build.gradle update classpath. For me 
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3' is working fine.